# Understanding different use for python 'for' keyword

Tags: python, list

I'm currently making a 'Hangman' type game in Python. I needed a way of checking if all of the correctly chosen letters were in the solution, so that a "YOU WIN!" message could be generated. I found a way to do this using the built-in 'all()' function by using this tutorial:

https://thispointer.com/python-check-if-a-list-contains-all-the-elements-of-another-list/

I made it work but I don't really understand it. I need help unpacking this line:

```
result =  all(elem in list1  for elem in list2)
```

Which, in plain English I assume means something like "the result is true if all of the elements in list1 are also in list2."

The exact meaning is a bit vague to me because I'm used to only seeing 'for' used in 'for' loops, where it is at the beginning of the line. Can someone clarify this? Also, what if I wanted to add another condition to the all() function? For example: everything in list1 is in list2 *and list3*.

**UPDATE**

Thanks @roganjosh for the clarification. After reading your message I've been experimenting a bit with this:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']
list4 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

# all of list1 is in list4
print('all(elem in list4 for elem in list1) == ' + str(all(elem in list4 for elem in list1)))

# All of list1 and list2 are in list4
print('all(elem in list4 for elem in list1 and list2) == ' + str(all(elem in list4 for elem in list1 and list2)))

# Not all of list1 and list3 are in list4
print('all(elem in list4 for elem in list1 and list3) == ' + str(all(elem in list4 for elem in list1 and list3)))
```

This is my first post on StackOverflow so thanks again to you and this wonderful community!

Comment: Close but the logic is reversed. For each element in list2 (`for elem in list2`) do a logical check to see if that element is in list1 (`elem in list1`), which will return either `True` or `False` on a per-element basis. If all of those logical checks are true, return `True`. Keep in mind that `list1` could, in theory, contain many more items than `list2` so the distinction of which way round the test is performed is important.

Comment: @roganjosh can you **bold** the all and add something about elem? seems like it would be a solid answer for chris here

Comment: Feel free to convert, I had a few moments on a phone and now I have to go into a meeting. It doesn't address the "different use of for", something needs to be said about the expression part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take the following examples

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l3 = [1,4,5,3,2]
l4 = [2,3]

l1_in_l2 = [elem in l2 for elem in l1]
l1_in_l3 = [elem in l3 for elem in l1]
l1_in_l4 = [elem in l4 for elem in l1]
```

**(1)** `(elem in list1  for elem in list2)` gives a generator object and means the same as

```
for elem in list2:
    # 'remember'(yield) if elem is in list1 or not
```

So for every element in list 2 it remembers if it is in list1 (True) or no (False). If you take a look at `list(elem in list1  for elem in list2)` you get a sense of that).

For the examples this would return

```
[True, True, True]    # l1_in_l2
[True, True, True]    # l1_in_l3
[False, True, True]   # l1_in_l4
```

**(2)** the `all` method then just checks if this `list` has only True values in it (which is the case if all elements of `list2` could also be found in `list1`).

For the examples this would return

```
True   # all(l1_in_l2)
True   # all(l1_in_l3)
False  # all(l1_in_l4)
```

**(3)** you are flexible with adding conditions. E.g.`all(elem in l2 and elem in l3 for elem in l1)` is an possible example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I've found this subject to not be intuitive at all, but working though examples seems to be the best way of approaching it. I understand it much better now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you place an expression within an `all()` function or similar it becomes a *generator expression*.

So this:

```
result =  all(elem in list1  for elem in list2)
```

Is the same as this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,4,5]

def contains(l2, l1):
    for item in l2:
        yield item in l1

result = all(contains(list2, list1))
```

`all()` extracts each value from the given *iterator* and checks if all elements evaluate to *True*.

So basically the *generator expression* or *contains()* function above resolves to:

> [True, False, False]

So you get:

```
result = all([True, False, False])
```

> Where *result* is `False`

You can add as many conditions as you like, but as the *generator expression* grows more complex, it's probably better to unpack it into it's own function/generator and build the list/iterator separately.